# Responsive text-shadow SCSS

Tags: reactjs, sass

I'm trying to put a responsive `text-shadow` property on my titles (that gives a depth effect).

I kind of succeeded to do it with JSX variables, but it's no use since I need it to be scss only, because the `font-size` will be determined here.  I would maybe need a scss var getter than would give the current font-size at any time.

Here's the kind of solution I'm looking for (scss):

```
@extend %font-something;  

text-shadow: $fontSize * 1px $fontSize / 2 * 1px $fontSize / 14 * 1px #00000029;
```

Note that `%font-something` can change the `font-size` to any size.

**Is this possible given the scss technology ?**

Answer (score 0):

Interesting topic. Yes, this is indeed possible.

You might use an one-liner:

```
$font-size: 16;

.foo {
  text-shadow: #{$font-size * 1px} #{($font-size / 2) * 1px} #{($font-size / 14) * 1px} rgba(#000, .16);
}
```

Or, a solution like this:

```
$font-size: 16;

$offset-x: $font-size * 1px;
$offset-y: ($font-size / 2) * 1px;
$blur-radius: ($font-size / 14) * 1px;
$color: rgba(#000, .16);

$text-shadow: $offset-x $offset-y $blur-radius $color;

.bar {
  text-shadow: $text-shadow;
}
```

**Edit:**

```
@mixin depth($font-size) {
  text-shadow: #{$font-size * 1} #{($font-size / 2) * 1} #{($font-size / 14) * 1} rgba(#000, .16);
}

p {
  @include depth(16px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking for something that do not force me to keep track of a variable, but more like a getter for anytime I use `font-size = x;`. So my question is, does it even exist?

Comment: @RémyMachado, Sure this is easily done, by using a `@mixin`